# Why does this while loop give me a syntax error?

Tags: java, syntax

this code:

```
@Service
public class IvsImport {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(IvsImport.class);

    @Autowired
    FileReader fileReader;

    @Autowired
    ValueProcessorProvider provider; 

    CSVEntryParser<IvsBerichtPojo> entryParser = new AnnotationEntryParser<IvsBerichtPojo>(IvsBerichtPojo.class, provider);
    CSVReader<IvsBerichtPojo> ivsBerichtReader = new CSVReaderBuilder<IvsBerichtPojo>(fileReader).entryParser(entryParser).build();

    public IvsImport(){}

    public FileReader getFileReader() {
        return fileReader;
    }

    public void setFileReader(FileReader fileReader) {
        this.fileReader = fileReader;
    }

    Iterator<IvsBerichtPojo> it = ivsBerichtReader.iterator(); //this } is not OK????
    while(it.hasNext()) {
            IvsBerichtPojo bericht = it.next();
            logger.info(bericht.getScheepsNummer()); 
    }
} //and here?????
```

gives me a syntax error on the } after the iterator declaration and at the last curly brakcet:

```
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
```

but when i do this, nothing changes....

Please help!

Comment: When are you going to run that piece of code?

Comment: yeps sorry, long day....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are writing the code directly in the class body, which is incorrect. Instead, your code should be part of some method.

```
public void logDetails(){
    Iterator<IvsBerichtPojo> it = ivsBerichtReader.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        IvsBerichtPojo bericht = it.next();
        logger.info(bericht.getScheepsNummer()); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You cannot write code outside method. You need method to write executable code.

Put your while loop into any method and see that it is compiled.

Answer (score 4):

because your while loop exists out of any other methods. You must put it into a method.

Answer (score 4):

you cannot write such code outside the method/constructor. you can only declare variables at that level. put the code with the while loop inside a **method body** and your compiler error would disappear .

More to add, you can only write methods/constructors/ initialization blocks/variable declaration inside a class body.

Answer (score 1):

Write your code in a method because a method is required to execute that code. Hence put your while loop in any method.
Thanks!!